# Instagram API Access Limit

Tags: instagram

We require to get the followers data (profile metrics specially follower's friends count) for my client's accounts having more than 500k followers. Because of Instagram api limitation we can only do 5k calls /hour. Thats why, it is impossible to load all followers data for every day. But there are few products like web.stagram.com etc, which are also using the instagram api and making unlimited (or some greater num than allowed limit) calls.

Are these partners exempted by instagram?

Please update if there is a way to get higher api limit.
We are ready to pay amount for the higher limit.

Regards,
Parvendra Adhran

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be directed at the vendor for support.

Comment: You can use multiple access tokens to fetch data from instagram;

Answer (score 2):

You have to try to get whitelisted to get a new Rate Limit, there's a long waiting list and Instagram has mentioned they won't be getting to the requests anytime soon.

I've heard of people still waiting over 2 months so far.

Comment: How do you apply for the whitelist? Any ideas?

Comment: Google "whitelist instagram api" and I'm sure you can find the answer.

Comment: Already did. This was the 1st result. Doesn't look promising at all. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/instagram-api-developers/4tsLyZzvV9c/CWj_uoi9mxwJ